# Multiple windows pop up when compiling PDFs (LyX)

Tags: lyx, miktex

To view my document in LyX (Windows), I click the view button and it compiles a PDF. But it does this by opening multiple (around but not always 5) instances/windows of the same PDF file in Acrobat reader and its really annoying. Does anyone who how to stop this? (Im using MikTex 2.9 if that useful)

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling both LyX and Acrobat reader (I know, obvious suggestion)?

Otherwise I'd try resetting your LyX preferences. You might have accidentally messed something up.

Comment: There should also be an »update« button next to the »view« button which shouldn't open the pdf but only update it.